# Jquery to display next button once a input button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show the 'next button' once the user clicks on the inputs, so they only get the next button after they have made a selection, I am using bootstrap for this project.

Fiddle is of what I have so far.

Any help appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/RS41/dvgxga2j/1/

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" name="1" class="a"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px; margin-bottom:15px; border-radius:0px;">A</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" name="1" class="b"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">B</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" name="1" class="c"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">C</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

   <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" name="1" class="d"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">D</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

</div>
<br / >
<br / >

<div align="left">
<button class="btn btn2 btn-default" name="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

UPDATE..

Hi, the whole point of the button is to move onto the next screen, I have implemented the above code, but when I go to the next screen the next button already appears, I would have thought this solution would be for all the screens. my fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RS41/dvgxga2j/9/

Comment: same ids for multiple elems are invalid way of writing markup.

Comment: where is the radio button ? it is not appear in your given fiddle

Comment: Thanks, that was a little error, thanks for point out to me.

Comment: Thanks Guys, all sorted now!

Comment: @Sole Okay, Feel free to accept the answer then.

Comment: @Mangesh Hi, the whole point of the button is to move onto the next screen, I have implemented the above code, but when I go to the next screen the next button already appears, I would have thought this solution would be for all the screens. my fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RS41/dvgxga2j/9/

Comment: I have used @Dipali's answer, but it does not work on multiple screen.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note:** You are repeating the use of same ID (`option2` and `option3`) on different elements, which is wrong.

In a simple way, you can do this using jQuery:

#### Disable / Enable

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("label input").click(function () {
        $(".next").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
input {vertical-align: middle;}
input[type=button] {padding: 2px 5px; margin: 5px 0;}
ul li {padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 2</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 3</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 4</label></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" class="next" value="Next" disabled="disabled" />
```

#### Hide / Show

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("label input").click(function () {
        $(".next").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
input {vertical-align: middle;}
ul li {padding: 5px;}
input[type=button] {padding: 2px 5px; margin: 5px 0;}
.hidden {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 1</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 2</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 3</label></li>
  <li><label><input type="radio" name="one" /> Item 4</label></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" class="next hidden" value="Next" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the button a class:

```
<button class="btn btn2 btn-default myButton" name="next">Next</button>
```

Hide the button using JS (that way it is still visible for people with JS switched off) or CSS:

```
$(".myButton").hide();
```

Attach an event listener to the radio buttons to alter the button's display property when they are clicked:

```
$("input:radio").on("click", function(){
  $(".myButton").show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/98n3dtd8/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/2/) :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#nextbtn').hide();
  $('input:radio').change(
    function() {
      $('#nextbtn').show();
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" name="1" class="a" /> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px; margin-bottom:15px; border-radius:0px;">A</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" name="1" class="b" /> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">B</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" name="1" class="c" /> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">C</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</label>
  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4" name="1" class="d" /> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">D</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div align="left">
  <button id="nextbtn" class="btn btn2 btn-default" name="next" style>Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks thats all sorted now.

Comment: Hi Dipali, I have some slides I want the same action on but this does not happen my code so far is: http://jsfiddle.net/RS41/dvgxga2j/9/

Comment: I have seen the fiddle works same as my fiddle for 1st slide. can you tell me what exactly you want to do ? and I can not see any previous button in html which is present in JS

Answer (score 0):

Here is your desired solution:

```
$('[name="next"]').addClass('disabled');
$('[name="options"]').on('change',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[name="next"]').toggleClass('disabled', !$('[name="options"]:checked').length);
})
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/5/)

Comment: `toggleClass` with a `boolean` parameter would be more efficient. e.g. `$('[name="next"]').toggleClass('disabled', !$(this).prop('checked'));`

Comment: Note: You left the invalid duplicate IDs in your example.

Comment: Yes. My concern was JS. Questioner can take care of the duplicate ID's.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed some of unnecessary attributes (like ids, second names and classes) from your radio buttons, add to the Next button class, which makes it invisible in default and using simple jQuery action I'm trying to find the first change of value in radio buttons.

The jQuery code should look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
        $("#next_button").removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

This is triggered every time someone hits any of the radio buttons. And when it happens jQuery removes class "hidden" which makes it visible.

Class hidden should look like this:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

That's all that you need.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/6/

Comment: Thanks Mike what If i have something like the following http://jsfiddle.net/RS41/dvgxga2j/9/

Comment: Well, at first, try to avoid using same name property for more than one HTML element (of course excluding radio buttons etc.). If you want to mark more than one element, use class, it's cleaner in my opinion. Then you also need only one Next button, it is doing the same job again and again, so why do you want to use more than one button. And finally, to make disappear on the next screen, just add hiding Next button after someone clicks it. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/23/