# jQuery Next button on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Previously I have this:
[Jquery to display next button once a input button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291830/jquery-to-display-next-button-once-a-input-button-is-clicked/27292230#27292230)

Now I need to get this button on the next slide to function in the same way as the first slide. 
Please see my code:

[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/RS41/dvgxga2j/9/)
Just a snipped below

```
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" name="1" class="a"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px; margin-bottom:15px; border-radius:0px;">A</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" name="1" class="b"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">B</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

  <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" name="1" class="c"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">C</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

   <label class="btn btn-default">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" name="1" class="d"> <span class="label num" style="font-size:18px;margin-bottom:15px;border-radius:0px;">D</span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
  </label>

</div>
<br / >
<br / >

<div align="left">
<button id= "nextbtn" class="btn btn2 btn-default" name="next" style>Next</button>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I cant see the next button in the fiddle.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, yes but it needs to appear after the user has clicked a choice, like the first slide

Comment: ohh, I thing the bhushan's answer is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for sliding, issues is in the `next` button display. As you have used below code to show/hide button where you have used `id="nextbtn"` for both next button.

```
$(function(){
  $('#nextbtn').hide();
  $('input:radio').change(
    function(){
       $('#nextbtn').show();
    }
);
```

In jQuery, you must not use same id for multiple elements, so either remove it or rename it to unique ids.

lets say `id="namebtn1"` and `id="namebtn2"`, and modify below code

```
$("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {
        //hide current button after click
        $(this).hide();
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).fadeIn(); // show next
    });

  $(function(){
     //hide button
     $('button[name=next]').hide();
     $('input:radio').change(
        function(){
         //show button for clicked div
         $(this).closest('div[class^=item]').find('button[name=next]').show();
     });          
  });
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/17/)**

**NOTE** - you have `$(document).ready(...` and `$(function(){..` in your code, both are meant for same purpose i.e. run script after all DOM elements loads and no need to put multiple time (though your code will work).

So remove either of them and put whole script inside one (i.e. `$(document).ready(...` or `$(function(){..` ) as shown **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/19/)**

Comment: Hi Bhushan, thanks for this, what if I wanted to add a previous button to appear also?

Comment: In that case you need to add click handler for previous button and show /hide in same way as doing for next button, i.e. add prev button show / hide where next button code is present.

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/26/), where I have added previous button and hiding it when page loads. I am hiding both buttons if any one of them gets clicked (see button click handler). Also showing both buttons if any of the row get selected.

Answer (score 0):

updated, see http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/18/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.wrapper>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide().first().fadeIn();
    $("button[name=next]").click(function (e) {                
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).fadeIn();
        $(e.target).hide();
    });
});
```

you can just move the next button outside and hide it after showing the next div